# Updating Included CSS File in header

Tags: php, css

```
app dir



          css

              style.css

          inc

              header.inc.php

              footer.inc.php

  index.php

  login.php

  register.php
```

style.css is included in the header.inc.php

```
<?php

//Include a error reporting:

include '../../errorReport.inc.php';

// Set default timezone:

define('TZ', date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles') );

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>

    <title>

    <?php

    if(defined('TITLE'))

    {

        print TITLE;

    } else {

        print 'Raise High the Roof Beam! A J.D. Salinger Fan Club';

    }



    ?>

    </title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./c/screen.css" media="screen,projection" />

</head>
```

Upon creating a new page(login.php) the goal is adding styles to the include(d) CSS in the header. Not simply placing the css anywhere in the mark-up, the following is my attempt, it has failed:

```
<?php

header('content-type:text/css', replace);

header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", (time()+900)) . " GMT");

$errorColor = '#900';

echo '.error{ color: '.$errorColor.'; }';

?>

<?php include 'inc/header.inc.php';?>

<p class=\"error\">Error MSG</p>

<?php include 'inc/footer.inc.php';?>
```

This is printed to the UA:

```
.error{ color: #900; }
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
    Raise High the Roof Beam! A J.D. Salinger Fan Club  </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./c/screen.css" media="screen,projection" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
.................................
```

Comment: If you're outputting a text/css mime-type, then the whole document should be css. adding in some HTML just makes for invalid/broken css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.error{ color: #900; }` needs to be inside a `<style>` tag inside `<head>`, not at the very top of the document.

```
<?php
    header('content-type:text/css', replace);
    header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", (time()+900)) . " GMT");

    $errorColor = '#900';
    $css        = array();
    $css[]      = '.error{ color: '.$errorColor.'; }';
?>

<?php include 'inc/header.inc.php';?>
<p class="error">Error MSG</p>
<?php include 'inc/footer.inc.php';?>
```

Then, inside `inc/header.inc.php`, have something like this within your `<head>` tag:

```
if (is_array($css)) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">' . implode("\n", $css) . '</style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I removed the header() from the target file, and the css array() worked as desired. Also, looking into opening and rewriting the css file with PHP. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you should include this CSS in your style sheet, style.css, because it is constant.

If you want this to be dynamic, you will need to modify your scheme a bit. This is where a framework would be helpful because any choice you make will be a bit of a hack. That being said, consider these options:

A) In login.php, set `$headerCss = '.error { color: '.$errorColor.'; } '`, then in header.inc.php, right before the `</head>` tag, add:

```
if ($headerCss) {
    print '<style type="text/css">';
    print $headerCss;
    print '</style>';
}
```

B) Another possible hack is to set `$pageName = 'login'`, then have a switch that tests for the page name in header.inc.php, like:

```
if ($pageName == 'login') {
    print '<style type="text/css">';
    print '    .error { color: #900; }';
    print '</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to the following, inc/header.inc.php:

```
<?php 
//Include a error reporting:
include '../../errorReport.inc.php'; 
// Set default timezone:
define('TZ', date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles') );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
    <?php
    if(defined('TITLE'))
    {
        print TITLE;
    } else {
        print 'Raise High the Roof Beam! A J.D. Salinger Fan Club';
    }

    ?>
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./c/screen.css" media="screen,projection" />

    <?php
    if(is_array($css)) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';

    foreach ($css as $constant)
    {
        //print"<p />$prop";
            foreach($constant as $vars){

            echo  $vars;

            }
    }
    echo '</style>';
}   
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <p class="description">A J.D. Salinger Fan Club</p>
        <h1><a href="index.php">Raise High the Roof Beam!</a></h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="books.php">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- header -->

    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>Favorite Quotes</h2>
            <p class="news">I don't exactly know what I mean by that, but I mean it.<br />- <em>The Catcher in the Rye</em></p>
            <p class="news">I privately say to you, old friend... please accept from me this unpretentious bouquet of early-blooming parentheses: (((()))).<br />- <em>Raise High the Roof Beam, Carpenters and Seymour: An Introduction</em></p>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->

    <div id="content">
        <!-- BEGIN CHANGEABLE CONTENT. -->
```

CSS TEST:

```
<?php
$errorColor = "#900";
$fontSize = "5em";


$cssColors = array('.error{ color: '.$errorColor.';}');
$cssfontSize = array('#mainHead{font-size: ' . $fontSize.';}');
$css = array('colors' => $cssColors, 'fontSize' => $cssfontSize);

?>

<?php include 'inc/header.inc.php';?>
<p class="error">Error MSG</p>
<?php include 'inc/footer.inc.php';?>
```